# codeigniter best way to create controller for editing a db row

Tags: codeigniter

Im new to codeigniter and im developing my first web application with it and want to make sure im doing best practices the 1st time so i dont have to go back to make corrections down the road. with that said, here is what im doing.

I want to edit a note in the DB, then after the record has been updated redirect to a different page.

my model is coded correctly so im not worried there, but the controller looks like this (and this is probably not correct:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $this->load->model('Notes_model');

    if (isset($_POST["edit"]))
    {
    $data['data']  = $this->Notes_model->edit($id);
        $url = "/Notes/view/" . $id;
        redirect($url);
    }
    $data['notes'] = $this->Notes_model->viewNotes($id);
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('notes/edit', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

}

hopefull this makes sense, basically what I'm wanting to do here is:
1.) Show the edit note page
2.) if i edited that page by hitting submit
    a.) update the db
    b.) redirect to a different page.

does this look pretty good or should i make some better changes?

Answer (score 0):

Although your controller code is fine but one thing you have to take care that you should `load model` in the `constructor` of your controller so you don't have to include the model in  each function same recommendations for the `libraries, helpers` this is the best practice

```
class myclass extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->model('Notes_model');
 $this->load->helper(form);
 }

 public function myfunction(){

 }
}
```

Here is the starting tutorial with `MVC` standards [advanced-codeigniter-techniques-and-tricks](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/advanced-codeigniter-techniques-and-tricks/)

Comment: thanks for the reply, one more question how would i create a form to update the db? my codes not working, so i want to start from scratch and create a form that will update the table NOTES

Comment: go through this link http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Form-Showing-Single-Data-for-Form-Edit-P263.html according to your needs and then post your code if you are facing some problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->m_auth->notLogin();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('ajax_pagination');
    $this->load->library('dateconverter');
    $this->load->helper('template');
    $this->load->helper('check');
    $this->load->model('mymodels/crud_model');
    $this->lang->load('personal',  $this->m_auth->get_language());
    $this->lang->load('global',  $this->m_auth->get_language());        
}

function index()
{
    $this->get_recs(); 
}

function get_recs()
{
    //get for view or first page to be showed
}
/**
 * Register New User
 */
function updateRecords()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('ministery','<span class="req">(Ministry)</span>','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('directorate','<span class="req">(Directorate)</span>','trim|required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
        header_tpl($this->m_auth->get_language(),'a');
        banner_tpl($this->m_auth->get_language(),'a');
        left_tpl($this->m_auth->get_language(),'a');
        $content = $this->load->view('personal/edit_personal',  $this->POST,true);
        content_tpl($content);
        footer_tpl();
    }
    else
    {
        $form_data = array(

                    'ministry'            => $this->input->post('ministery'),
                    'directorate'         => $this->input->post('directorate'),
                    'job_province'        => $this->input->post('job_province'),
                    'job_district'        => $this->input->post('job_district'),
                    'first_name'          => $this->input->post('fname'),
                    'last_name'           => $this->input->post('lname')

                     );


       if($this->crud_model->update_recs('ast_emp_property',$form_data)==TRUE)
       {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","<span class='m_success'>".$this->lang->line('global_insert_success')."</span>");
            redirect('/home/success_reg/'.$id.'','refresh');
       }
       else
       {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("msg","<span class='m_error'>".$this->lang->line('global_insert_error')."</span>");
            redirect('home','refresh');
       }
    }

}
```

}
?>